# Math, circles, interior points and densities

Tags: algorithm, math, random

The theory is this: I have a circle C of radius R and centre S. Inside this circle, I want to place N (a "big" number) points such that the density of points in the vicinity V of a point P is equal everywhere in the circle for all points. As N goes to infinity and the vicinity goes to P, the density function in both polar and cartesian coordinates becomes a constant.

So, how should I approach this if I wanted to populate the circle with N points of constant density?

Comment: Definitely belongs on: http://mathoverflow.net/

Comment: Nonsense, it is an algorithm question that belongs here. On Mathoverflow it would be closed immediately as too trivial.

Comment: @psasik: Have you ever looked at MathOverflow? This is not the kind of question you'd ask there. If this is not an algorithm question, then I don't know what it'd take to qualify as one. There are, after all, more than 3000 questions tagged as algorithm here.

Comment: I agree, mathoverflow.net is very picky more so than stackoverflow. They will consider it trivial.

Comment: "the density function in both polar and cartesian coordinates becomes a constant" What does density in polar coordinates mean? Is it even possible to have constant density in both coordinate systems?

Comment: @starblue: I might be a complete layman here, but I don't see anything strange with that. To me, a point in system 1 is the same point in system 2 and its vicinity looks the same in both cases, regardless if we describe the point in (x,y) or (r,theta).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [Disk Point Picking](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiskPointPicking.html). You generate a random theta (0 to 2*pi) and a random r (0 to 1), both distributed uniformly. The points would then be:

```
x = Sx + R*sqrt(r)*cos(theta)
y = Sy + R*sqrt(r)*sin(theta)
```

Another possibility is to generate points in the bounding square, and reject points that lie outside the circle.

Edit: This would make the probability density function constant in cartesian coordinates (which is probably what you want), but not in polar coordinates, since larger r would have higher probability. You can't have both of them be constant.

Comment: interjay, you correctly realized that if its constant in one set of coordinates then its not in the other. This is a mathematical property, implying that the opening post is an ill-posed problem.

Comment: also, you should not generate the points in a square and reject to get constant density in cartesian co-ordinates. That screws with the random process, changing the density. Instead just choose random variable 0 <= X <= 1 and 0 <= Y <= sqrt(1-X^2)

Comment: oops should include the -1 <= X <= 1 and -sqrt(1-X^2) <= Y <= sqrt(1-X^2)

Comment: @gmatt, but then there would be higher density at the right and left sides (X near +/- 1) where Y would have a smaller range.